# use --login-path=local in perl DBD::mysql

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, dbd-mysql

mysql supports passwordless login using stored local authentication credentials in a file named .mylogin.cnf (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html) for more details).

for example:

```
mysql --login-path=local
```

My questions is: how to do this in perl using DBD::mysql?

Comment: DBD::mysql doesn't describe it in the docs, and neither does DBI give hints about it.

Answer (score 3):

DBD::mysql uses the MySQL C API, which doesn't appear to support login paths. As an alternative, you can use an [option file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) and the [`mysql_read_default_file`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql#mysql_read_default_file) and `mysql_read_default_group` options in your `connect` call:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use DBI;

my $dsn = 'DBI:mysql:' .
          ';mysql_read_default_group=local' .
          ';mysql_read_default_file=/path/to/config';

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, undef, undef, {
    PrintError => 0,
    RaiseError => 1
});
```

Your option file should look something like this:

```
[local]
host     = localhost
database = foo
user     = myuser
password = mypassword

[remote]
host     = remote.example.com
database = foo
user     = myuser
password = mypassword
```

Note that unlike .mylogin.cnf (the file used by `--login-path`), regular option files are not encrypted. This isn't as big of a problem as it might sound. The main benefit of encryption is that it prevents you from accidentally exposing your credentials, e.g. when viewing the file, but it doesn't provide unbreakable security. You can still protect your option file by making sure it's not world-readable, excluding it from version control, etc.

Comment: Is this still true, or have the binaries been updated?

Comment: As far as I know, nothing has changed. I don't see anything suggesting that the MySQL developers are even working on adding this functionality. Maybe you should submit a feature request.